# Python Exceptions Handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, exception, try-catch

My code downloads files from an online file storage web service and unzip them. To run my script, I give it a date as argument (as mentioned here below). I want to add an error message if the date did not match any documents.

This is the code in question :

```
if key_element.startswith(date):

    date_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d%b%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    if not os.path.exists(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+parentKey):
           os.makedirs(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+parentKey)
    key.get_contents_to_filename(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+keyString)


    for f in glob.glob(working_directory+ '/' + date_file+ '/'+ 'usrm' + '/'+ file_name+ '*.zip'):
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'a')
        zip_ref.extractall(working_directory + '/' + date_file+ '/'+ 'usrm' + '/' + file_id)
        zip_ref.close()
        os.remove(f)


else:
    print 'ERROR MESSAGE : Your search did not match any documents. Try rynning with another date.'
```

With a wrong date, it works. I have the error message.

Strangely, with a valid date, my code is normally running, but I have also the error message !

I even tried with this :

```
if key_element.startswith(date):
    try:                
        date_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d%b%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        if not os.path.exists(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+parentKey):
               os.makedirs(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+parentKey)
        key.get_contents_to_filename(working_directory+ '/' +date_file+ '/'+keyString)



        for f in glob.glob(working_directory+ '/' + date_file+ '/'+ 'usrm' + '/'+ file_name+ '*.zip'):
            zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'a')
            zip_ref.extractall(working_directory + '/' + date_file+ '/'+ 'usrm' + '/' + file_id)
            zip_ref.close()
            os.remove(f)

    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR MESSAGE : Your search did not match any documents. Try rynning with another date.', e)
```

With a wrong date, I have nothing. The error message is not displayed.

PS :

- a valid date : an existing folder wich contains informations about the date in question (example : 01Jul2016) etc
- a wrong date : an unexisting folder in my online file storage web service (example : 07Aug2016).

What might be wrong? Any help appreciated. Thx !

Comment: Can you post the code as text? Also, your `try` block is blindly catching every exception: can you remove it and tell us what the *real* exception is?

Comment: Posting your code as an image makes it much harder for us to work with, and some people will just give up instead of trying to help you.

Comment: With a wrong date (i.e. something not formatted correctly as a date), wouldn't it just not even encounter the `try/except` statement since they're contained within the `if` statement? If you want to display your own error message, use `raise`.

Comment: @DataAddicted, could please provide some more info about what you consider a **valid** date and what the param **date** looks like?

Comment: So `if key_element.startswith(date)` is supposed to be validating the date?  I don't see how -- unless this code is part of a larger loop which you haven't shown us.

Comment: a valid date : an existing folder wich contains informations about the date in question (example : 01Jul2016) etc

Comment: So assuming `date` is `01Jul2016` or a tuple of valid dates, and `key_element` is a folder name, having a date outside of these valid names would not do anything in your second block of code. In your first block (i.e. the one with `if/else`), it wouldn't make sense for a valid date to run correctly and output the error message unless you're seeing an error from a subsequent invalid date. Try printing `key_element` in the first block to see.

Comment: All :  thank you for a quick reaction. I posted the code as text ! Sorry for that !

Comment: @brianpck The real exception is an unexisting folder in my online file storage web service.